# Stuck on Consecutive Moduli Selection (Residue Number System)

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, coprime

I'm preparing for my final year project in school and i plan on working on the implementation of Residue Number System in Image Processing. 
I found this thesis online by **Pallab Maji** here:

http://ethesis.nitrkl.ac.in/2831/1/Thesis_Final_App_of_RNS_in_Comm__SP.pdf

and i'm currently stuck on generating a Moduli Set, however i checked page 17 which is about Consecutive Moduli Selection and with this

Theorem:

Let ${N_{1}, N_{2}, N_{3} ... N_{k}}$ be a set of k consecutive co-prime numbers. Let these numbers be expressed as : $N_{i} = N_{1} − m_{i−1}$

for i=1,2,3 . . . k, where $m_{i−1} > m_{i−2} > m_{i−3} > ...m_{i−k} > 0$. Let $N_{k+1}$ be another number
that can be added to the set of co-prime numbers, i.e. $N_{k+1} = N_{1} − m_{k}$ then $N_{k+1}$ will be
co-prime if $gcd(N_{i},m_{k} − m_{i−1}) = 1$, for i=1,2,3 . . . k.

I've been able to identify $N_{1} = 2^{m} - 1$.

Given an example like:

Choose co-prime numbers with b=32 and k=4, i.e., close to $2^{8} (= 256)$, gives us P = {255, 254, 253, 251} using the consecutive moduli selection.

It's known that $m = b/k$ so $m = 8$ therefore,

$N_{1} = 2^{m} - 1 = 2^{8} - 1 = 255$

$N_{2} = N_{1} - m_{i-1}$

So i've not been able to identify the values of $m_{i - 1},m_{i - 2},....$. and i would like to calculate the remaining values for $N_{2}$ to $N_{4}$

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. As for identifying the $m_{i-1}, m_{i-2}, \ldots$, based on what I read in that thesis, you're looking for the co-prime values which are closest to each other. If so, then one of the simplest ways is to get the prime factors of each of the current $N_i$ from $N_1$ to $N_k$ and then find the next smallest integer which has no prime factor in common with any of the previous values. If it's only a few values, for a relatively small starting value, you can do this manually, else you can program a computer to do this.

Comment: @JohnOmielan thanks for the response, do you mind pointing me to a resource that can guide me in doing it manually?

Comment: @JohnOmielan basically my question is how do i calculate the remaining values for $N_{2}, N_{3}, N_{4}$??

Comment: @paniola Re: manually finding $N_2$, $N_3$, $N_4$, etc., there are several strategies. One fairly good one is to determine each prime factor of the previous #'s & then strike off their multiples from a list of lower numbers (roughly similar to how the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) works). For example, if $3$ is a factor of $N_1$, you can cross off $N_1 - 3, N_1 - 6, N_1 - 9, \ldots$, & if $5$ is also a factor, you can also strike off multiples of $5$ less. If you do this for all prime factors, the largest # not struck off is relatively prime.

Comment: @JohnOmielan thanks but i'm not sure i fully understand what you meant, from the example the factors of $N_{1} = 255$ are $3,5,17$ and i don't the part you said "For example, if 3 is a factor of 1, you can cross off _{1}−3,_{1}−6,_{1}−9,…, & if 5 is also a factor, you can also strike off multiples of 5 less. If you do this for all prime factors, the largest # not struck off is relatively prime."